# gcsfuse terminating with error 1 on GKE Autopilot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcsfuse

I am trying to use gcsfuse from a kubernetes pods running in GKE Autopilot.
I read there may be issues with GKE autopilot, but the error I got is different from what is typically reported.

Is gcsfuse now working with Autopilot or there is no hope?
And the csi-fuse driver a possible option instead on GKE Autopilot?

Here's the error I see:

```
root@gcs-k8s-test:/mnt# gcsfuse  gs://bucketXXXX /mnt/fuse
2022/08/16 01:32:17.656053 Start gcsfuse/0.41.5 (Go version go1.18.4) for app "" using mount point: /mnt/fuse
2022/08/16 01:32:17.781937 Opening GCS connection...
2022/08/16 01:32:18.164009 Mounting file system "gs://bucketXXXX"...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running /bin/fusermount: exit status 1
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you happen to try out https://github.com/ofek/csi-gcs ?

Answer (score 0):

If you`ll try to enable a gcsfuse debug ( gcsfuse --foreground --debug_fuse --debug_fs --debug_gcs --debug_http bucket_name /local/mount/folder ), it will probably show an error regarding  "/usr/bin/fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first" .
It seems that gcsfuse pod requires privileged mode along with "SYS_ADMIN" capabilities. However, such capabilities are not allowed by GKE Autopilot. (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/497)